# SQL query selecting public IP address

Tags: postgresql, ip, postgresql-8.3

I am on a postgresql 8.3 database. I am trying to figure out where the mistake is in the query below.  I am trying to design a query to only select source_ips and destination_ips that are private addresses.

For some reason one of the addresses that is grabbed in the query below is the address 208.117.252.39 which is not a private address.

> Is there something wrong with the logic in the query below that would make it select public IP addresses as well?

```
 select source_ip, destination_ip
from ip_table
where
    (
    inet '10/8' >> source_ip
    or inet '192.168/16' >> source_ip
    or source_ip >= inet '172.16/16' and source_ip < inet '172.32/16'
     )
    and  inet '10/8' >> destination_ip
    or  inet '192.168/16' >> destination_ip
```

Comment: Is it the same if you change >= to >> and < to >> ?

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, try replacing "source_ip >= inet '172.16/16' and source_ip < inet '172.32/16'" with "inet '172.16/12' >> source_ip". That private range is represented as a /12 CIDR and does not need to be handled specially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to appropriately group your final conditions. Right now, the last "or" ignores all of the `source_ip` conditions.

Structure the query as such:

```
select source_ip, destination_ip
from ip_table
where
(
  inet '10/8' >> source_ip
    or inet '192.168/16' >> source_ip
    or inet '172.16/12' >> source_ip
 )
and  (
  inet '10/8' >> destination_ip
    or  inet '192.168/16' >> destination_ip
    or inet '172.16/12' >> destination_ip
);
```

Note the destination clause is grouped together.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `and` operation has priority over `or` you are missing a parenthesis. Your query is equivalent to:

```
select source_ip, destination_ip
from ip_table
where
    (
        (
        inet '10/8' >> source_ip
        or inet '192.168/16' >> source_ip
        or source_ip >= inet '172.16/16' and source_ip < inet '172.32/16'
        )
        and  inet '10/8' >> destination_ip
    )
    or  inet '192.168/16' >> destination_ip
```

The correct version:

```
select source_ip, destination_ip
from ip_table
where
    (
        inet '10/8' >> source_ip
        or inet '192.168/16' >> source_ip
        or source_ip >= inet '172.16/16' and source_ip < inet '172.32/16'
    )
    and
    (
        inet '10/8' >> destination_ip
        or  inet '192.168/16' >> destination_ip
    )
```